# Permission denied in Django makemessages

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-admin, manage.py

I'm trying to add i8n into a Django app, but when I execute:

```
(venv) user@machine:~/path/to/repo$ django-admin makemessages -l es
```

The next error is thrown:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Jinja2-2.9.5.dist-info/LICENSE.txt.py'
```

But if I use it with manage.py instead of django-admin it works correctly. In django documentation they recommend to use django-admin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `./manage.py`, there's a reason django creates this shortcut with the project. I've only ever used `django-admin` to create a new project (obviously there's no `manage.py` before the project is created), everything else is done with `./manage.py`

Comment: But why do they keep writing the examples with `django-admin` in django documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files

Comment: This is document here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's doc does not really "recommand" to use `django-admin` instead of `./manage.py` - actually [the doc states that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/):

> Generally, when working on a single Django project, it’s easier to use manage.py than django-admin.
>   (...)
>   The command-line examples throughout this document use django-admin to be consistent, but any example can use manage.py or python -m django just as well.

The reason being that:

> In addition, manage.py is automatically created in each Django project. manage.py does the same thing as django-admin but takes care of a few things for you:
>   It puts your project’s package on sys.path.
>   It sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file.

*NB actually the second point is not totally exact - `./manage.py` only sets `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` if it's **not** already set in your environnement.*

So when using `django-admin` you have to make sure that it will find your settings module (either by settings the environnement variable or by passing it with the `--settings` option) and that your project's root is in your pythonpath.

Actually, except for the `startproject` command - where, by definition, you don't already have a `./manage.py` file -, there's no reason to use `django-admin` at all unless you want to explicitly use a different settings module without changing your environnement variable.

Comment: You're welcome - but I just searched the doc, you know  ?-)