# Django makemessages writes fake files

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm getting an odd error when I make the i18n files of a django project:

```
(venv) user@machine:~/path/to/repo$ django-admin makemessages -l es
```

It creates fake `.py` files for every `.txt` files:

For example, `requirements/base.txt`

```
Django==1.10.6
django-environ==0.4.1
djangorestframework==3.6
psycopg2==2.7
djangorestframework-jwt==1.9.0
Markdown==2.6.8
unipath==1.1
```

It generates a `requirements.base.txt.py` with 'XXXXXX' in it:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But it also creates the right `.po` files into `/locale`
Could you please point me in the right direction? Because I'm lost. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the same problem when using `./manage.py` instead of `django-admin` ?

Comment: I also have a related problem with `manage.py` and `django-admin` (in another question) but I tried to isolate both problems. Now I am not able to run it with django-admin. Could it be related? :)

Comment: It is (and I just saw your other question).  The difference is that `manage.py`  will set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable (if it's not already set) while `django-admin` wont. If you really want to use `django-admin` you must set this environment variable before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is here : [Permission denied in Django makemessages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718942/)

To make a long story short: `makemessages` misbehaves because it doesn't know your project's settings. Actually this should be reported as a defect (if it hasn't already) since most other commands that needs the settings to properly work detect the fact and do raise an `ImproperlyConfigured` error with an explicit message.

Answer (score 5):

For everyone that is having the same problem, this can also occur if you **haven't created a locale/ folder within each app** of your Django project, as it's the default folder if none specified in your settings.

After creating it, my problem went away.

[More info in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files)